# Vous vous y êtes mis à combien pour

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

Quelqu’un peut m’aider à comprendre ce [tweet](https://twitter.com/sophiaaram/status/1373174037636075520?s=21) ?

Dites @JeanCASTEX , vous vous y êtes mis à combien pour m'autoriser à prendre l'air à 10km et obliger mon chiens à rester à moins d'1km de sa niche ? #pervers

C’est quoi la construction utilisée dans ‘vous vous y êtes mis à combien’ ?

Merci !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Se mettre à quelque chose* signfie "commencer une tâche, une action". P.ex.: *il s'est mis à manger*. Pour remplacer le complément introduit par "à", on utilise le pronom "y": *il s'y est mis*.
En langage courant, par ellipse, on peut utiliser *s'y mettre* pour exprimer l'idée de commencer à travailler, même si ce que ce "y" est n'est pas clairement exprimé.
Ex: *on va s'y mettre après le repas* signfie "on va commencer notre travail"

*À combien* est une forme interrogative pour demander "combien de personnes". C'est la question correspondant à l'usage de "à" avec un nombre pour désigner le nombre de personnes qui participent à une activité..
Ex: *nous avons fait du vélo à cinq* => *à combien avez-vous fait du vélo ?*

Le sens de la question (qui est sarcastique) est le suivant: *combien de personnes ont été nécessaires pour travailler sur l'idée de m'autoriser à prendre l'air* ?

Comment: Merci, le ‘à combien’ m’avais confondu, c’est clair maintenant.